# How to use a DSLR as a webcam on raspberrypi

Tags: pi-2, php

I want to use My DSLR(canon 7d) as a web cam for one of my project what i did is that i installed libphoto2(Becose canon 7d supports ptp protocol)in my Pi(Ubuntu mate installed) all the commands associated with libphoto2 is working fine other ways able to capture images using this software. What i want to do is that i want to see a live preview from the camera over my browser so that i can capture images from my system. Other ways around how to use monitor connected to pi as the monitor for DSLR.

> Why i want to do this

I am working with a php software called http://www.blaize.net/2014/04/gphoto-webui-a-php-web-ui-for-gphoto2/ When i load this software there will be a capture button if i press on that capture button the software will capture an image and load on memory card    I want to get a live preview along with this,So that i can arrange camera by looking at the monitor  how can i achieve this?
More generally i want a live preview from the camera over my monitor through browser.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47159/discussion-on-question-by-arunwebber-how-to-use-a-dslr-as-a-webcam-on-raspberryp).

Answer (score 3):

You have an HDMI output from the camera that supplies clean HDMI, so you need to convert that to an input format for the Rpi. I don't have a good way to do this, but I think you'll discover that you run into another problem fairly quickly.  The live video feed from DSLRs turns off after about 30 minutes with no activity (button presses, recording, etc.).  I know this because we tried several different brands and types of cameras to webcast a conference.

The reason for this is not obvious but involves importation regulations regarding DSLRs and camcorders.  (You'll find some commentary about the CMOS chip heating up, etc. which I find unconvincing at best.)  Basically, the camcorder business interests would have a terrible time competing with just mounting a DSLR instead since they are much cheaper and usually better quality (low-light, etc.).  If your requirement is for 30 minutes or less of monitoring you could be okay.  Try it out with your camera before you go to the trouble of building an interface.

Comment: +1 For recommending the OP double check the camera even allows for this kind of operation (and the observation about the sneaky role business interests often play in limiting technology).

Comment: HDMI converter to pi could be an option?

Comment: If i convert HDMI out put from the camera to PIs input will i be able to get a live view of camera to a browser?

Comment: @goldilocks Is it possible to generate live view of camera over browser?